# JOINING TABLES AND COUNTING

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to count total number of child records from a table but seems not to work. When in left join is counts rather the total number of records in the parent table rather than the child.

```
SELECT Count(comment) as total
FROM dbo.photo_comment  LEFT JOIN users_pics ON photo_comment.resp_email = users_pics.email
WHERE photo_comment.wardrobe = MMColParam
```

photo_comment is the parent table and users_pics is the child table. What i want the query to do is to count the total number of comments on a picture

Comment: need to identoify what the Primary key of the pictures table, and the comments table,  and 2. Shouldmn't you nbe joining on the PictureId, (or whatever the Picture Primary key is), not on the email?,  and 3) the tables are in the wrong order, you should be joining Pictures, Left Join to Commenmts, nopt the other way around.  Pictures is the parent, and comments are the children.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by the picture.  I assume it'd be something like this, based on the name of the field that identifies the picture:

```
SELECT  COUNT(comment) ,
        user_pics.picture
FROM    dbo.photo_comment
        LEFT JOIN users_pics ON photo_comment.resp_email = users_pics.email
WHERE   photo_comment.wardrobe = MMColParam
GROUP BY picture
```

Comment: didn't work everyone comment on each picture appears on its own instead of grouping

Comment: That may be related to the field you're joining on.  Can you post your table structures?  Don't you have a pic_id or something like that you can join on?

Comment: i join with two email fields from both tables

Comment: What I'm saying is that may be a problem.  Are there any email addresses associated with multiple pics?  What about comments from multiple pics?

Comment: yes there are email address associated with multiple pics